# URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): ):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth

I am trying to implement an OAuth provider in Rails 3. When I try to authorize a client app I get this error.  I am using the RESTful auth plugin and pelles OAuth-plugin.  When I was testing via the Rails console and getting this error I thought that I simply needed to encode the URLs but I get the same error when testing in browser so I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I got into trouble with `URI.split` (returning this error), I don't know if this helps you, but I will post here some warnings for also someone else having this error:

1. Check your url is not nil, and it's a valid one.
2. Do `URI.encode(url)` before `URI.parse` (to avoid special characters)
3. Do `strip` to the string you pass to `URI.parse` (to avoid leading and trailing whitespaces).

All in one:

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))
```

Related resource: http://www.practicalguile.com/2007/09/15/raising-uriinvalidurierror-from-a-perfectly-valid-uri/

Comment: Doing that still didn't help me split the url up. Any advice on that? I was able to find a hint on using custom uri part matchers here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#comment-726255789, but I'm not sure what to override for my issue (query params have chars not accepted by `URI.split`).

Comment: I actually think I'm going to use plain 'ol regex for what I need to do, actually. `URI.split` seems like it's an incomplete parser of rfc3986, so it might just be better to bypass it and save some headaches.

Comment: where would you place this? in the search controller for example or in a config file? thanks!

Comment: `'https://example.com/[%23R]%20'` causes exception even after `URI.encode`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this alternative URI gem: https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable

There is no such problems with it.

Very native, just add namespace in your code after installing the gem

```
Addressable::URI
```

Comment: This gem should not be considered as a replacement. They are closing bugs that require more than a minute to think about with a reason: "I don't think compatibility between Addressable::URI and URI is a goal of the Addressable project" (c) https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/issues/373#issuecomment-575052012

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
safeurl = URI.encode(url.strip)
response = RestClient.get(safeurl)
```

Comment: Can you add details in your answer please ?

Comment: `'https://example.com/[%23R]%20'` causes exception even after `URI.encode`

Answer (score 0):

I'm here because I faced an issue with the fastlane. It's been written with Ruby thus my answer can be helpful.

In my case, I had the environment variables `http_proxy = XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX` and `https_proxy = ...`
When I changed them to `http_proxy = http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX` and `https_proxy = https://...` respectivle the issue has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when attempting to parse links that contained the `@` symbol in them, e.g. `https://tiktok.com/@username`.

Since `URI.encode` is deprecated I used `link.strip.gsub('@','%40')` instead.