# How to fix bad URI is not URI

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, uri

I'm using the ruby version `1.9.3`, I like to get host name from the video url below,

I tried with code

```
require 'uri'
url = "https://ferrari-view.4me.it/view-share/playerp/?plContext=http://ferrari-%201363948628-stream.4mecloud.it/live/ferrari/ngrp:livegenita/manifest.f4m&cartellaConfig=http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/config/&cartellaLingua=http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/config/&poster=http://pusher.newvision.it:8080/resources/img1.jpg&urlSkin=http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/swf/skin.swf?a=1363014732171&method=GET&target_url=http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/swf/player.swf&userLanguage=IT&styleTextColor=#000000&autoPlay=true&bufferTime=2&isLive=true&highlightColor=#eb2323&gaTrackerList=UA-23603234-4"  
puts URI.parse(url).host
```

it throws an exception URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):

I tried with encode the URL then parse like below

```
puts URI.parse(URI.parse(url)).host
```

it throws an exception same `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)`

But above code works for the below URL.

url = http://www.youtube.com/v/GpQDa3PUAbU?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1

How to fix this? any suggestion please.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374470/uriinvalidurierror-bad-uriis-not-uri

Comment: In a case of proxy usage this one can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427832/911408

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This url is not valid, but it works in browser because browser itself is less strict about special characters like :, /, etc.

You should encode your URI first

```
encoded_url = URI.encode(url)
```

And then parse it

```
URI.parse(encoded_url)
```

Comment: You really saved my time. 
In my case I faced **Net::HTTPBadResponse - wrong status line: "{":** problem and same solution applicable for that

Comment: I end up with `NoMethodError: undefinded method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass` when I try this. However, when I run the Gem Manually, the code works.

Comment: I was also seeing `undefinded method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass`, but it turned out that my original `url` was nil when I didn't expect it.

Comment: This is not reliable, ex. URI.parse(URI.encode("https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/16110726/Scorpion.S03E05.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION[ettv]")) still renders the error

Comment: @Laser url without protocol (http) is not valid either

Comment: @KonradSzczęśniak try the actual link in quotes, stackoverflow converted the literal string example into the format there.

Comment: @KonradSzczęśniak `URI.parse(URI.encode("https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/16110726/Scorpion.S03E05.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION[ettv]"))`

Answer (score 21):

Addressable::URI is a better, more rfc-compliant replacement for URI:

```
require "addressable/uri"
Addressable::URI.parse(url).host
#=> "ferrari-view.4me.it"
```

`gem install addressable` first.

Comment: I think this response is more accurate, because ruby URI.encode does not work with some URIs

Comment: Addressable::URI.parse("https://www. with_space.com").host will not work, it will raise an Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError

Comment: Steam uses urls like `https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/[U:1:123456789]` and `URI.encode` doesn't help but `Addressable` does.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
safeurl = URI.encode(url.strip)
response = RestClient.get(safeurl)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this solves the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your URI query is not valid. There are [several characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding) that you should encode with `URI::encode()`. For instance, `#`, , or `&` are not valid in a query.

Below a working version of your code

```
    require 'uri'

    plContext = URI::encode("http://ferrari-%201363948628-stream.4mecloud.it/live/ferrari/ngrp:livegenita/manifest.f4m")
    cartellaConfig = URI::encode("http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/config/")
    cartellaLingua = URI::encode("http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/config/")
    poster = URI::encode("http://pusher.newvision.it:8080/resources/img1.jpg")
    urlSkin = URI::encode("http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/swf/skin.swf?a=1363014732171")
    target_url = URI::encode("http://ferrari-4me.weebo.it/static/player/swf/player.swf")
    url = "https://ferrari-view.4me.it/view-share/playerp/?"
    url << "plContext=#{plContext}"
    url << "&cartellaConfig=#{cartellaConfig}"
    url << "&cartellaLingua=#{cartellaLingua}"
    url << "&poster=#{poster}"
    url << "&urlSkin=#{urlSkin}"
    url << "&method=GET"
    url << "&target_url=#{target_url}"
    url << "&userLanguage=IT"
    url << "&styleTextColor=#{URI::encode("#000000")}"
    url << "&autoPlay=true&bufferTime=2&isLive=true&gaTrackerList=UA-23603234-4"
    url << "&highlightColor=#{URI::encode("#eb2323")}"  
    puts url
    puts URI.parse(url).host
```

Answer (score 0):

`URI.parse` is right: that URI is illegal. Just because it accidentally happens to work in your browser doesn't make it legal. You cannot parse that URI, because it *isn't* a URI.

Comment: According to which rfc?

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))
```

Comment: I think this is wrong because it's return the same link