# Can't successfully find a Twilio subaccount with twilio-rb

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

Big fan of using twilio-rb over twilio-ruby, but i'm stuck when trying to provide the Twilio subaccount's friendly_name to request the account_sid.

app.rb

```
Twilio::Config.setup \
  :account_sid  => '[MAIN ACCOUNT_SID]',
  :auth_token   => '[AUTH_TOKEN]'
```

subaccount.rb

```
post '/subaccount/create' do
  Twilio::Account.create :friendly_name => params[:friendly_name]
  account = Twilio::Account.find :friendly_name => params[:friendly_name]

  @subaccount = Subaccount.new
  @subaccount.friendly_name = params[:friendly_name]
  @subaccount.account_sid = account.sid
  if @subaccount.save
    redirect '/subaccount/create'
  else
    erb 'There has been an error saving.'
  end
end
```

It creates the subaccount in Twilio just fine, it does not however find the subaccount with the friendly_name.

When I break this down further, I have a subaccount named 'hello' and I want the SID for it:

```
account = Twilio::Account.find :friendly_name => "hello"
puts account.sid
```

This is what is returned in the Terminal

```
Called from: /Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/builder.rb:86:in `new'.
URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?): /Accounts/{:friendly_name=>"hello"}.json:
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.10.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:44:in `path='
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.10.2/lib/httparty/request.rb:33:in `initialize'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.10.2/lib/httparty.rb:456:in `new'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.10.2/lib/httparty.rb:456:in `perform_request'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/httparty-0.10.2/lib/httparty.rb:398:in `get'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/twilio-rb-2.3.0/lib/twilio/resource.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in singleton class'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/twilio-rb-2.3.0/lib/twilio/finder.rb:9:in `find'
/Users/chadsakonchick/Projects/cloud-phone/lib/subaccounts.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1603:in `block in compile!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `[]'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:985:in `route_eval'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:966:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1006:in `block in process_route'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `catch'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1004:in `process_route'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:964:in `block in route!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `each'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:963:in `route!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1076:in `block in dispatch!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1073:in `dispatch!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `block in call!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `block in invoke'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `catch'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1058:in `invoke'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:898:in `call!'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:217:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:210:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2014:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `block in call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1788:in `synchronize'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
[2014-11-07 18:22:32] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for #<String:0x007fc7548fa570>
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:37:in `rescue in call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:180:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2014:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `block in call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1788:in `synchronize'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1478:in `call'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/chadsakonchick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
localhost - - [07/Nov/2014:18:22:32 CST] "GET /subaccount/twilio-rb/hello HTTP/1.1" 500 340
```

Comment: This any use? :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700784/how-to-fix-bad-uri-is-not-uri

Comment: @MickStevens Sadly, I don't think so. The formatting is exactly as it states here - https://github.com/stevegraham/twilio-rb - when I take out the :friendly_name => params[:friendly_name] and replace it with an Account_SID in order to display the friendly name, it works like a charm. It's only when i'm trying to give it the friendly_name parameter that it refuses to cooporate with - URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?): /Accounts/{:friendly_name=>"hello"}.json:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
account = Twilio::Account.all :friendly_name => "hello"
puts account[0].sid
```

It took me a few minutes of digging in the [`twilio-rb` gem](https://github.com/xmjw/twilio-rb/blob/master/lib/twilio/finder.rb#L27), it's the `Finder` class that is being included into the Account class that does the work. In this scenario we want to use the API List resource which [Stevie](https://twitter.com/stevegraham) and co supported with the `all` method with a filter parameter.

Using the `find` method requires the account SID, and doesn't seem to support parameters. I think it might be worth making a pull request to add this to the documentation, as it's not obvious.

**Update**

See above as I added the `[0]` indexer to `account` as this is an Array.

Comment: That makes sense @xmjw, but when I use .all I get:
NoMethodError - undefined method `sid' for #<Array:0x007fd89934cff0>:
when I use your exact code.

Comment: Ah, you may be getting multiple accounts back. Try:  `puts account[0].sid `?

Comment: ZOMG, if you were here I would bear hug you! That makes obvious sense(now). Thanks a ton for the help!