# valid url is causing rest-client to throw bad URI (trying to work with an awful API)

Tags: ruby, uri, rest-client

The following is a valid URL in the browser (I know, browser is less strict).

> https://api.siteconfidence.co.uk/current/30294ie0sdafhwe89rh5/Return/[Account[AccountId,Pages[Page],ServiceStatus[HighestStatusCode]]]/AccountId/123123jjh/Id/213123123/StartDate/2015-08-12/StartTime/12:00:00/EndDate/2015-08-07/EndTime/07:05:05/StatusCode/1

However when I give it to rest-client it just throws a `bad URI(is not URI?).

So, none of the things I've tried after having read the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700784/how-to-fix-bad-uri-is-not-uri) work. They all give various errors, like can't gsub addressable, undefined method match, etc.

I'm not sure what next to do.

I know it's not real uri but that's how their API is (rubbish I know, but I can't change it)

Also, I can't put the `[]` bit in quotes, there API just ignores it.

EDIT:

I changed the places holders for fake values.

Comment: `$account_id` works in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I Solved the problem by just doing something else.

I used the Curb gem to make the request and then used the JSON gem to parse the output (after ensuring the return format is JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is url encoding it automatically. You have characters in there that are invalid in a url. You need to encode it before you try making a request with it.