# Use Hash value on url with Nokogiri or RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, rest-client

I have a url like :

`http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das`

In my browser I can get data from that url, but if I'm use nokogiri

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das'))
```

I get

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das
from /home/worka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
```

Also with RestClient

```
RestClient.get 'http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das'
```

I got same an error.

Comment: `Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com/test?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das'))` =>
`OpenURI::HTTPError: 404 Not Found`. Can you write your URI?

Comment: @Ilya I think write original uri in stackoverflow is bad idea, but I will edit common with original url in my quetion.

Comment: Nokogiri has nothing to do with a bad URI; It's not aware of that level of the code and instead only reads the stream if one is passed to it, and parses the resulting string. OpenURI or RestClient are the layers that would be returning that error. It's important to understand what components in your code do what. Please remove the references and tag for Nokogiri and replace them with OpenURI and your question will make more sense.

Comment: Where did you get the sample URI? Is it generated from your code? If so, your question seems like an XY problem where you're asking about Y but should ask about X, which is how to generate the URI.

Comment: @theTinMan URI from a third party, they provide a URI for my purposes site, so I can't do anything to change it. 

Oh, About wrong question, yeah that's my question, unclear what you're asking?, At least there are some people who understand, although my english is not good. But thanks for suggestion and double down vote from you.

Answer (score 0):

Encode your url first then use it.

```
url = 'http://172.0.0:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das'
encoded_url = CGI::escape(url)
Nokogiri::HTML(open(encoded_url))
```

Comment: I got `Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long @ rb_sysopen`

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with URIs, it's a good idea to use the tools designed for them such as URI, which comes with Ruby.

The URI can't be

```
http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das
```

because the `data` component is invalid. If you are adding `data` then I'd start with:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?sign=x6das')
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"sign"=>"x6das"}
data = {"foo" => "bar","joe" => "doe"}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(query.merge(data)) # => "sign=x6das&foo=bar&joe=doe"
uri.to_s # => "http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?sign=x6das&foo=bar&joe=doe"
```

Your initial example using `{"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}` is JSON serialized data, which usually isn't passed in a URL like that. If you need to create JSON, start with the initial hash:

```
require 'json'

data = {"foo" => "bar","joe" => "doe"}
data.to_json # => "{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"joe\":\"doe\"}"
```

`to_json` serializes the hash into a string, which could then be encoded into the URI:

```
data = {"foo" => "bar","joe" => "doe"}

uri = URI.parse('http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?sign=x6das')
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"sign"=>"x6das"}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(query.merge('data' => data.to_json)) # => "sign=x6das&data=%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%2C%22joe%22%3A%22doe%22%7D"
```

But again, sending encoded JSON as a query parameter in the URI is not very common or standard since data payload is smaller without the JSON encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I got solved my problem

```
url = http://172.0.0.1:22230/test.action?data={"foo":"bar","joe":"doe"}&sign=x6das
RestClient.get(URI.encode(url.strip))
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code isn't going to run. You didn't declare `url` correctly.

Comment: It isn't about declare url, but how "I" can solve to deal with url like that and  I've found useful solution for my problem from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700784/how-to-fix-bad-uri-is-not-uri), and that's working for me.