# Concatenation of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to concatenate the ":" sign with value that is inside a variable but when trying to concatenate it shows me the following error: bad URI(is not URI?): :208

This is the code I am trying to concatenate in the ApplicationController:

```
  def set_database

    if usuario_signed_in?
      empresa = ':'+(current_usuario.empresa_id)
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(empresa)

  end
```

With the previous code does not work, but replacing the variable as follows does not show the error:

```
if usuario_signed_in?
  empresa = :'208'
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(empresa)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah those are 2 different things

```
empresa = ':'+(current_usuario.empresa_id)
```

would probably resolve to a string or an error while

```
empresa = :'208'
```

is a symbol.

I believe you can solve this issue by just converting your empresa to a symbol, either by calling

```
current_usuario.empresa_id.to_sym
```

OR

```
current_usuario.empresa_id.to_s.to_sym
```

Comment: my assumption is that you're getting the right results with the second portion of your code

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly with your second option. But I can not understand, how is :'208' a symbol? And just put empresa = (current_usuario.empresa_id).to_s.to_sym do not need to put ':' at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the URL is not valid, you need to encode it and parse it.  See [How to fix bad URI is not URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700784/how-to-fix-bad-uri-is-not-uri)