# not an HTTP URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am calling the circle.so api using ruby on a rails on a code that I got from postman.

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port);
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["Authorization"] = "phdbM12mVAiEyLF19UjoYdiU"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

While working perfectly in postman, It does not work on my app, with an error of

```
ArgumentError in TopicsController#index
not an HTTP URI
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `URI("http://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")` ?

Comment: check this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700784/how-to-fix-bad-uri-is-not-uri

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify `http://` in your url string

```rb
url = URI("http://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")
```

If you ommit the scheme (http://) part, then ruby does not know what specific URI type this is.

```rb
2.6.3 :005 > url = URI("hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")
 => #<URI::Generic hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members>
```

But if you specify the scheme (http://) then you'll get

```rb
2.6.3 :003 > url = URI("http://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")
 => #<URI::HTTP http://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members>
```

Note the different class (`URI::Generic` vs. `URI::HTTP`).

There are many other types of URI, e.g.:

```rb
2.6.3 :007 > url = URI("file://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")
 => #<URI::File file://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members>
2.6.3 :008 > url = URI("ftp://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members")
 => #<URI::FTP ftp://hub.atlas.fm/api/v1/community_members>
```

You can find more here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html