# bad uri google places from heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, google-places-api

I have a Google Places API key and was able to successfully query the Google Places API from my localhost.

I am on Rails 3.1, and when I pushed my site to Heroku I get a bad request. I am referring to the http google places API and NOT the javascript one - although I suspect the problem would be the same either way (see the message I get from Google below)

Here is how my account is configured in the Google Console:

```
Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key:    
XXXXXX
Referers:   
Any referer allowed
Activated on:   Mar 5, 2013 9:41 PM
Activated by:    xx@stanford.edu –
```

There was no problem when I was on the local host.

However when I push the app and then make a query to Google Places this is what I get:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=blamp&key=XXXXX&sensor=false&types=restaurant|food|bar|cafe
```

EDIT: 
I've pinpointed the error is because of my usage of the bars '|' to separate the google types at the end. however this works both when I copy/paste the query to my browser header, and when I do this in development on localhost. Any ideas:

1) Why this is happening.
2) How to fix it?

Here is how I access the API with Ruby code:

```
query = URI.escape(params[:search])
        url_params = "json?query="+ query + "&key="+ GOOGLE_API_KEY + "&sensor="+ false.to_s + "&types="+GOOGLE_TYPES.join("|")
        url_params << "&pagetoken="+params[:next_token] if params[:next_token]
        url = URI.parse("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/"+url_params)


        http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)

        result = http.request(request)
        JSON.parse(result.body)
```

A note on GOOGLE_TYPES: this is a global constant that is actually an array; I join it with "|" then pass it to the URL.

The problem is that when I URI.encode the string, the query does not return any resutls for simple requests like "steak house san francisco", whereas before the URI.encode it did. Obvs the query becomes useless if it can't return proper results like it did on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should encode your URL. Its a good practice to always encode urls with requests and parameters. This may be of some help: [URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): ):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374470/uriinvalidurierror-bad-uriis-not-uri)

EDIT:
The url character "|" might not be safe, therefore need to url-encode such queries.

Try this:

```
def search_google_places
  api_key = 'xxx'
  base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=' + api_key
  tail_url = '&query=garena&sensor=false&types=restaurant|food|bar|cafe'
  main_url = base_url + api_key + tail_url
  url = URI.parse(URI.encode(main_url))
  response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: 
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
     http.get url.request_uri
  end

  case response
     when Net::HTTPRedirection
        # repeat the request using response['Location']
     when Net::HTTPSuccess
        outputData = JSON.parse response.body
     else
        # response code isn't a 200; raise an exception
        pp response.error!
     end
     return outputData
end
```

Comment: This actually passes the symbol, but then when I run the query it shows no results on queries that were successful before the encoding. Let me explain: in localhost, I didn't encode the string or strip it. The search query returned all sorts of valid results. Now, when I run the query after encoding, the search comes up empty.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you are accessing the api via ruby code? Perhaps its a ruby related issue.

Comment: I updated my answer, You may wanna use `URI.parse(URI.encode(xxxx))`