# Sentry InvalidURIError with DSN url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry

O configure my Ruby on Rails application to use sentry with error report, but it show-me this error:

> URI::InvalidURIError:
>   bad URI(is not URI?): 'http://9ba0c50c55c94603a488a55516d5xxx:xxxx6d6468a4cb892140c1f86a9f228@sentry.myaddres.com/24'

When I remove `9ba0c50c55c94603a488a55516d5xxx:xxxx6d6468a4cb892140c1f86a9f228@` this part of addresss all works fine, but in [sentry documentation](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby) is:

```
Raven.configure do |config|
  config.dsn = 'http://public:secret@example.com/project-id'
end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to encode it. The special characters in the url are throwing it off. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374470/uriinvalidurierror-bad-uriis-not-uri

Comment: This is not the problem, but help-me to found. I put address in ENV var with comas... this is a problem, I remove the comas and works. THANKS :D

Comment: awesome! glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

I was using `ENV var` to set sentry `DSN`:

```
# .env
SENTRY_DSN_URL='http://public:secret@example.com/project-id'
```

and in `initializer`

```
Raven.configure do |config|
  config.dsn = ENV['SENTRY_DSN']
end
```

This problem is the **quotation marks**. To solve just remove them.

```
# .env
SENTRY_DSN_URL=http://public:secret@example.com/project-id
```

Works fine.