# encode_www_form_component problem with Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

At the moment I'm rewriting a whole application from Rails 3 to Rails 6.

In that process I'm cleaning a lot of things as well.

But here is my problem.

I have a module called `Reusable` which as it name implies contains a ton of reusable methods across the models.

We use `Faraday` to establish connection to the certain server:

Old code looked like this:

```rb
module Reusable
  def self.establish_connection(url)
    url = I18n.transliterate(url)
    url = URI.encode(url)
    conn = Faraday.new(url: url) do |builder|
      builder.use :cookie_jar
      builder.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
      builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    conn.get
    conn
  rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
    message = "(Timeout::Error) Connection to address: #{url} failed. If address is reachable please run the method again."
  end
end
```

However, by moving to Ruby 2.7.0, we've got the dreaded `URI.encode` is obsolete warning.

In order to get rid of it, I rewrote a whole part like so:

```rb
module Reusable
  def self.establish_connection(url)
    url = I18n.transliterate(url)
    url = URI.encode_www_form_component(url)

    conn = Faraday.new(url: url) do |builder|
      builder.request :url_encoded
      builder.use :cookie_jar
      builder.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
      builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    conn.get
    conn
  rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
    message = "(Timeout::Error) Connection to address: #{url} failed. If address is reachable please run the method again."
  end
end
```

Hoewever, I'm getting this:

[image: reusable_image]

I've searched the SO for the solution to this problem, and I found this -> [URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): ):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374470/uriinvalidurierror-bad-uriis-not-uri)

But this again returns me to using the `URI.encode` which I want to avoid.

Any solution to this, or should I just quietly ignore the obsolete warning for now until something better comes out?

Comment: Can you add an example of an URL that did raise an error in your old version but fails in the new version?

Comment: Yes. https://www.joyn.de

Comment: form/query parameters should pass in encode_www_form_component rather than a url

Comment: @kiddorails the thing is that we receive the URL from the frontend side. After that, it is rendered as a String on the backend in the first place in controller function, and we then use this method. But thinking about the usage you mentioned, that might be a good strategy, to remove the intermediate step of converting to String in controller, and just use the form params directly with the module function. Thanks for the tip. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module Reusable
  def self.establish_connection(url)
    url = I18n.transliterate(url)
    params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(URI(url).query)

    conn = Faraday.new(url: url, params: params) do |builder|
      builder.request :url_encoded
      builder.use :cookie_jar
      builder.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
      builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end
    conn.get
    conn
  rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError, Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
    message = "(Timeout::Error) Connection to address: #{url} failed. If address is reachable please run the method again."
  end
end
```